# A step in generalized Schwarz's Lemma proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Statement: If $f$ is an analytic endomorphism of $B_1(0)$ fixing the origin, then $\sum_{n \geq 0} \left|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right|^2 \leq 1$.

I have the following (sketch of proof): by Hurwitz's theorem, $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n$ for all $z \in B_1(0)$. If $0 < r < 1$, Gutzmer-Parseval inequality gives $$|a_1|^2r^2 + |a_2|^2r^4 + |a_3|^2r^6+\cdots\leq 1,$$where $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. Make $r \to 1^-$ and we're done.

I can't figure for the life of me what would go wrong if $a_0 \neq 0$. We'd have the extra term $|a_0|^2$ there and we'd pass the limit $r \to 1^-$ in the same way. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens, with

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n z^n,$$

the assumption $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$ gives

$$2\pi \geqslant \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(re^{i\varphi})\rvert^2 \,d\varphi = 2\pi \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert^2 r^{2n},$$

and we can take the limit $r \to 1^-$ without problems wether $a_0 = 0$ or not.

Comment: Then you're telling me that $f(0) = 0$ hypothesis is unnecessary? :P

Comment: Yes, only with more words.

Comment: Ah! A light bulb went on over my head now. The $f(0) = 0$ part only comes when we need to prove later that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$, right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hm, _I_ would prove that differently, The maximum modulus theorem says (for $f(0) = 0$) $$\biggl\lvert \frac{f(z)}{z}\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{r}$$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant r < 1$, and then $r \to 1^-$ gives $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert z\rvert$.

Comment: I really like that way better. Anything to escape from these terrifying series. Thanks again haha